# Is an OS X server necessary or preferable for doing CI iOS builds using Jenkins?

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild

I'm currently investigating whats required and how to set up an automated CI build system for creating iOS apps.

The intention is to use Jenkins as thats currently being used for other OS builds.

Does the OS X build machine need to be an OS X Server or can a regular version of OS X be used?

Thanks

Comment: Simple OSX Client Version (non-server) is entirely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use Jenkins in-house since quite some time (started when it was still called Hudson). We are using it installed on a regular OSX client. There is no need for OSX server to run a continuous integration server.